# Asynchronous Apex Limits

Tags: governorlimits, limits, asynchronous

I was recently trying to create a  `set<id> myset`, and then perform around 600 `.add('...id...')` calls, and finally select some records based on  `myset` values.

When trying to execute it it was always showing, without giving me any reason.

> Execution failed

I noticed that the maxim number of ids I was allowed to add was around 250-300.

1) Is there a known limit in terms of the execution time in in Asynchronous Apex ? (I know that in synchronous Apex is around 10 seconds, but never the less adding 600 items to a list shouldn't take anywhere close to 10 seconds).

2) How long does a `.add()` call take?

Answer (score 1):

1) We have 60,000 (60 Sec) CPU time limit in asynchronous process.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

2) There is no specific time for time taken by .add() method and it can take n number of values (no limit).

Comment: Adding an item into a set in apex is a constant-time operation (~O(1) complexity for those who know about big-O notation). We know this because the docs say that [an apex `Set` is really a Java `HashSet`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_sets.htm) in the back-end. Each individual call to `add()` takes some time which counts towards the CPU time governor limit, but the time each call takes is so small that it usually takes tens of thousands of calls to `add()` before you can see a clear effect on the reported CPU time used.